# App ignores values entered and always show one condition

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Well I deployed my app to my Android phone and wanted to test it bc my emulator just stopped working and i cant fix it. And sometimes it worked fine with 0 being entered and other times it crashed i thought it is bc of math error but i covered that case in my ViewModel I tried to fix it but now it wont show DisplayValidPrompt its like it dont exist and in any case will show DisplayInvalidPrompt whatever values are
EDIT:
Now app doesnt crash on 0 just on null values anywhere but still i got that covered in if statement in OnSubmit im so confused right now
ViewModel code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Papucometar.ViewModel
{
    public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Action DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt;
        public Action DisplayValidLoginPrompt;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        private string Name;
        public string name
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set
            {
                Name = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
        int x;
        private string LR;
        public string Lr
        {
            get { return LR; }
            set
            {
                if(Int32.TryParse(value, out x))
                {
                    if(x < 0)
                    {
                        Lr = "1";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    LR = value;
                }
                
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LR"));
            }

        }
        private string PI;
        public string Pi
        {
            get { return PI; }
            set
            {
                PI = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PI"));
            }
        }
        int x1;
        private string R;
        public string r
        {
            get { return R; }
            set
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(value, out x1))
                {
                    if (x1 < 0)
                    {
                        R = "1";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    R = value;
                }
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("R"));
            }
        }
        public ICommand SubmitCommand { protected set; get; }
        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            SubmitCommand = new Command(OnSubmit);
        }
        public void OnSubmit()
        {
            if (R == null || LR == null || PI == null || Name == null)
            {
                DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt();
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayValidLoginPrompt();
                ClearForm();
            }
        }

            private void ClearForm()
            {
                Name = string.Empty;
                Lr = string.Empty;
                Pi = string.Empty;
                R = string.Empty;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(name));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Lr));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Pi));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(r));
            }


            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

    }

}
```

and this is code behind:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Papucometar.ViewModel;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Papucometar.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginUI : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginUI()
        {
            var vm = new LoginViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = vm;
            if(vm.Lr == "0")
            {
                vm.Lr = "1";
            }
            vm.DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt += () => DisplayAlert("Slamas ga", "Sjebo si ga brate aj opet", "Popravi");
            vm.DisplayValidLoginPrompt += () => DisplayAlert("Nevidjena Papuca", $"{vm.name} je papuca velicine {Math.Abs(int.Parse(vm.Lr)*int.Parse(vm.Pi) / int.Parse(vm.r) )} bacvi na kvadrat", "Ok");
            InitializeComponent();
            name.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);
            };

            Lr.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);
            };
            Pi.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);
            };
            r.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);
            };
            
        }

    }
    

}
```

Im sorry for asking so many questions in last few days I tried to google it but cant find any solution to my problem.

Comment: What “math error” are you talking about?  Where **specifically** in the code is it crashing?

Comment: I thought it is bc of dividing with 0 but i cant see where it is specifically crashing bc emulator isnt working but now it isnt crashing but just wont display valid prompt its like it is completely ignores else in OnSubmit function

Comment: If the app is no longer crashing then using “crashing app” in the title of your post is very confusing.  Have you stepped through your code in the debugger?

Comment: Consider using [IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-8.0) instead of testing for null

Comment: It still crashes but now on null values sorry for that. Now i fixed emulator and it stopped crashing but still doesnt show other prompt no mather what are values it just shows Invalid prompt

Comment: I edited title now. It stoped crashing but still ignores values just shows InvalidPrompt

Comment: in addition to the other two suggestions I made, this line `Lr = "1";` should be `LR = "1";`. **AND** you are raising `PropertyChanged` events using the names of the private backing fields, not the public property names

Comment: Can you explain me why is it wrong to put PropertyChanged on private fields?

Comment: this `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LR"));` tells the UI "a property named **LR** has changed".  But you don't have a property named `LR`.  `LR` is a private field the UI can't access.  `Lr` is the name of the **public property** that the UI can access, so that is the name you should use in `PropertyChanged`

Comment: I changed PropertyChanged to public property and now i cant enter int values in Lr field and r field

Comment: Yeah bro i fixed it it was dumb thing from me i made if in if instead of just adding another  condition in first if. With this double if i havent covered what if number is able to parse and is bigger than 0 so I just put that condition in if. Now everything works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question-asker says “Now everything works”, and it looks to me like this discussion won’t be relevant to anyone else.